# Bring back to restoring state an online database

Tags: sql-server, failover, disaster-recovery, tsql, log-shipping

I configured logshipping for a database. I did some tests and tried a controlled failover.

During log shipping secondary db is in restoring state.

To have a controlled failover i stopped the primary database.
then i put online my secondary db with:

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks WITH RECOVERY
```

Then stopped the log shipping jobs in the secondary server and pointed my application (a website) to the secondary server.

Everything worked as expected.
Now i want to bring back online the primary server:
i started the primary server then i pointed the application to the primary server and restarted the logshipping jobs in the secondary server.
I only need to set the secondary db in restoring mode but the command:

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks WITH NORECOVERY
```

and it gives me the error:

> The database is already fully recovered. 
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

do i need to restore a backup in the secondary anyway?

which are the best practice in this case? how do i revert to the initial situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you recovered the database, the primary and the secondary diverged. So, you have to restore the LS secondary from a fresh backup of the primary and re-establish LS.